# How can I get two anchor elements to hover together?

Tags: html, css

By connect I mean that if you hover over the first one, the second one is underlined too and vice versa.

```
<a href="#">anker one</a> <a href="#">anker two</a>
```

Comment: Doing that might be a bad UX decision but you could wrap them both in one `span` tag and add `cursor: pointer;` to that span